# Debug an APT repository

Tags: ubuntu, apt

I've set up an APT repo on [sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/zotero-deb/files/repo/bionic/) and have added a sources.list with

```
deb https://sourceforge.net/projects/zotero-deb/files/repo/bionic bionic main
```

when I try to run `sudo apt update` I get an error:

```
Ign:21 https://sourceforge.net/projects/zotero-deb/files/repo/bionic bionic InRelease
Err:24 https://sourceforge.net/projects/zotero-deb/files/repo/bionic bionic Release
  Redirection from https to 'http://downloads.sourceforge.net/mirrorproblem?failedmirror=netix.dl.sourceforge.net' is forbidden [IP: 87.121.121.2 443]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'https://sourceforge.net/projects/zotero-deb/files/repo/bionic bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
```

but

```
curl -L https://sourceforge.net/projects/zotero-deb/files/repo/bionic/dists/bionic/main/binary-amd64/Release
```

does show the release file. How can I see what `apt` tries to access so I can debug this problem?

Comment: The problem is: "_Redirection from https to http [...] is **forbidden**_" No need any further debug.

Comment: I think there is though. If I look a the answer by @v13 I don't see the `mirrorproblem` URL in the list of redirects, so I still need to figure out with sourceforge why a `curl` fetch looks OK but and `apt-get` does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been answered as a response.

Also, curl follows the redirects. To see them try `-v`:

E.g. for me:

```
$ curl -v -L https://sourceforge.net/projects/zotero-deb/files/repo/bionic/dists/bionic/main/binary-amd64/Release |& grep Location
< Location: https://sourceforge.net/projects/zotero-deb/files/repo/bionic/dists/bionic/main/binary-amd64/Release/
< Location: https://sourceforge.net/projects/zotero-deb/files/repo/bionic/dists/bionic/main/binary-amd64/Release/download
< Location: https://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/zotero-deb/repo/bionic/dists/bionic/main/binary-amd64/Release?r=&ts=1539817154&use_mirror=vorboss
< Location: https://vorboss.dl.sourceforge.net/project/zotero-deb/repo/bionic/dists/bionic/main/binary-amd64/Release
```

Comment: Thank you! I was trying to figure out what URL `apt` actually tried to fetch so I can take the matter up with sourceforge. I know the answer of @ipor-sircer is part of it but I couldn't see what the initial URL was.

Comment: Turns out I forgot to run `reprepro -b sf/repo/ createsymlinks` -- super thanks, would not likely have found this without your help.